# Exclude from numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, numpy, import, ascii

I have to import large comma-separated tables as numpy arrays. Therefore, I am using genfromtxt to do so. However, I encountered that those tables include elements in parentheses of the form "foo,bar", which I don't even need.
During import numpy then raises an error that the number of columns in inconsistent, as it recognizes those elements as two seperate entries. How can I avoid that without knowing where those entries are located. And if that is not possible, is there a way to explicitly exclude certain colums from import, that might contain those values? I know of usecols, but I want the opposite. Also, usecols would probably also miscalculate the number of columns as well, so exclusion would not work this way.

Answer (score 1):

The 'invalid_raise' parameter might help:

```
invalid_raise : bool, optional
    If True, an exception is raised if an inconsistency is detected in the
    number of columns.
    If False, a warning is emitted and the offending lines are skipped.
```

With `False` your file should at least load.

But if you still need to use the offending rows, you'll need some other approach.

If all data fields line up, the column width version of `delimited` might work.

---

`genfromtxt` accepts a generator as input - that is, a function that can feed it one line at a time.

An example of using a `re` function to sanitize `(foo,bar)` strings in an input source:

```
def foo(astr):
    # replace (foo,bar) with (foo:bar)
    return re.sub(r'\(([^,]*)(,)([^,]*)\)',r'(\1:\3)',astr)
txt = 'foo,2,3\n(foo,bar),5,6\nbar,8,9\n'
txt = txt.splitlines()
np.genfromtxt((foo(i) for i in txt),delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

produces:

```
array([('foo', 2, 3), ('(foo:bar)', 5, 6), ('bar', 8, 9)], 
  dtype=[('f0', 'S9'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Or from a file

```
with open('stack27383639.txt') as f:
    F=np.genfromtxt((foo(l) for l in f),dtype=None,names=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but yes, I need those lines and they are not properly aligned.

Comment: I've added an example of using a small function to sanitize the input lines as they are passed to `genfromtxt`.